# I need suggestions about an implementation of Distributed Graph using MPI

Tags: graph, distributed, mpi

Do you happen to know any robust, well-recongnised software library which implements distributed graphs using MPI?

What I mean by distributed graph is a graph whose edges and vertices can be distributed over a cluster of processors in an abstract manner.

I need a good example to learn from.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The only library I'm aware of that meets your needs is the [Boost distributed graph library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/DistributedGraph.html):

> The Parallel BGL is primarily concerned with distributed graphs.
>   Distributed graphs are conceptually graphs, but their storage is
>   spread across multiple processors. [In the example] the graph has been
>   divided among three processors (represented by the grey rectangles).
>   Edges in the graph may be either local (with both endpoints stored on
>   the same processor) or remote (the target of the edge is stored on a
>   different processor).